# Accessing Camera and Renderer from a UMDF driver

Tags: uwp, videochat, umdf

We are upgrading our existing chat application to support Video chat, and in our existing architecture, we have following modules

1. UWP Applicaion- For user interaction
2. UMDF driver - Its has core stack for signalling with server and Tx , Rx of video data from/To server
3. WinRT component - Its for accessing UMDF driver from UWP App

My concerns are about accessing Camera and Renderer (video surface) and video codecs at UMDF module.

Is it possible to access Camera, video codecs and Video Surface from UMDF driver?

As UWP application module meant for user interaction, it has to create surface for rendering, Can I access handle of this surface at UMDF and render video data on it?

I have gone through few examples and API's for accessing Camera, video codecs and rendering and observed that all UWP API's are very closely integrated, not possible pass handle of surface or Camera to UMDF driver from UWP Application.

Does here I am missing something, does I can achieve video chat with my existing architecture?